# Configure static IPv4 and IPv6 address in OpenSuse 13.2

Tags: linux, ipv6, opensuse

Please help me to configure both IPv4 and IPv6 address to device eth0 in OpenSuse 13.2, i tried with the following parameters on ifcfg-eth0:

```
BOOTPROTO='static'
NM_CONTROLLED='no'
USERCONTROL='yes'
BROADCAST=''
ETHTOOL_OPTIONS=''
IPADDR='192.168.1.20/24'
MTU=''
NAME='eth0'
NETMASK='255.255.255.0'
NETWORK=''
STARTMODE='auto'
############# IPV6 #############
NETWORKING_IPV6='yes'
IPV6INIT='yes'
IPV6ADDR='2607:f0d0:1002:0011:0000:0000:0000:0001/64'
IPV6_DEFAULTDEV=eth0
```

The wicked service is working, when service restart the IPV6 address is not configured.

Thanks in advance. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply, reading a bit more i found the correct parameter to configure IPV4 and IPV6 address in OpenSuse 13.2, the network file config is:

```
BOOTPROTO='static'
BROADCAST=''
ETHTOOL_OPTIONS=''
IPADDR='192.168.1.20/24'
MTU=''
NAME='eth0'
NETMASK='255.255.255.0'
NETWORK=''
STARTMODE='auto'
IPADDR_0='2607:f0d0:1002:0011:0000:0000:0000:0001'
PREFIXLEN_0=64
```

I did ping6 test between two linux in my network and is correct. I hope this config helps someone.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what my box has, though with the exact numbers examplified; in particular, the IPv6 gateway device/router address may vary depending on exactly what your network offers. The output of `ip -6 a` and `ip -6 r` might also be handy for diagnostics (or without the `-6` if IPv4 "isn't working" as well).

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=foo.example.edu
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_AUTOTUNNEL=no
IPV6FORWARDING=no
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
NM_CONTROLLED=no
USERCONTROL=no
MTU=1500
HWADDR=00:00:36:AA:BB:CC
# IPv4
IPADDR=192.0.2.42
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.0.2.1
# IPv6
IPV6ADDR=fde4:8dba:82e1::1234
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=fe80::fde4:8dba:82e1:1%eth0
# DNS
DNS1=fde4:8dba:82e1::53
DNS2=192.0.2.53
$
```

I've also perforce disabled `NetworkManager` and instead have enabled the `network` service, so use `service network restart` (as this is a pre-systemd RHEL system) to restart the network.

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me for SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 v 11 .Both bonding , ipv4 and IPv6

```
host_name:/etc/sysconfig/network # cat ifcfg-bond0
STARTMODE='auto'
BONDING_MASTER='yes'
BONDING_MODULE_OPTS='mode=active-backup miimon=100'
BOOTPROTO='static'
IPADDR='10.120.xx.xxx/24'
IPADDR_0='2607:f480:111:xxxx:xxxx:xxx:379:aaaa'
PREFIXLEN_0=64
USERCONTROL='no'
BONDING_SLAVE0='eth6'
BONDING_SLAVE1='eth7'


 host_name:/etc/sysconfig/network # cat ifcfg-eth6
 STARTMODE='hotplug'
 BOOTPROTO='none'

 host_name:/etc/sysconfig/network # cat ifcfg-eth7
 STARTMODE='hotplug'
 BOOTPROTO='none'

host_name:/etc/sysconfig/network # cat /etc/SuSE-release
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 3
```